# How do I check a json object for the existence of a key with php server side?

Tags: php, arrays, json, object

Ok, So I am working with the reddit api using the php sdk wrapper by @jcleblanc ( https://github.com/jcleblanc/reddit-php-sdk )

That information is not necessarily relevant to the question but I want to give you a frame of reference so you understand what I am looking to do.

The api returns what I believe is a mixed json object as a response when I make calls to reddit. The response length varies and is not consistent. The only this that is consistent is if the action was successful, it returns the key pair

```
["success"]=> bool(true)
```

I want to basically search whatever is returned by the api for the key "success" and I can simply evaluate for true or false. Can anybody help with some code to do that?

Here is a sample complete return:

```
object(stdClass)#1171 (2) { ["jquery"]=> array(29) { [0]=> array(4) { [0]=> int(0) [1]=> int(1) [2]=> string(4) "call" [3]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(4) "body" } } [1]=> array(4) { [0]=> int(1) [1]=> int(2) [2]=> string(4) "attr" [3]=> string(4) "find" } [2]=> array(4) { [0]=> int(2) [1]=> int(3) [2]=> string(4) "call" [3]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(7) ".status" } } [3]=> array(4) { [0]=> int(3) [1]=> int(4) [2]=> string(4) "attr" [3]=> string(4) "hide" } [4]=> array(4) { [0]=> int(4) [1]=> int(5) [2]=> string(4) "call" [3]=> array(0) { } } [5]=> array(4) { [0]=> int(5) [1]=> int(6) [2]=> string(4) "attr" [3]=> string(4) "html" } [6]=> array(4) { [0]=> int(6) [1]=> int(7) [2]=> string(4) "call" [3]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(0) "" } } [7]=> array(4) { [0]=> int(7) [1]=> int(8) [2]=> string(4) "attr" [3]=> string(3) "end" } [8]=> array(4) { [0]=> int(8) [1]=> int(9) [2]=> string(4) "call" [3]=> array(0) { } } [9]=> array(4) { [0]=> int(1) [1]=> int(10) [2]=> string(4) "attr" [3]=> string(8) "redirect" } [10]=> array(4) { [0]=> int(10) [1]=> int(11) [2]=> string(4) "call" [3]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(66) "https://www.reddit.com/r/mysubreddit/comments/12hyas2/my_no_link_post/" } } [11]=> array(4) { [0]=> int(1) [1]=> int(12) [2]=> string(4) "attr" [3]=> string(4) "find" } [12]=> array(4) { [0]=> int(12) [1]=> int(13) [2]=> string(4) "call" [3]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(11) "*[name=url]" } } [13]=> array(4) { [0]=> int(13) [1]=> int(14) [2]=> string(4) "attr" [3]=> string(3) "val" } [14]=> array(4) { [0]=> int(14) [1]=> int(15) [2]=> string(4) "call" [3]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(0) "" } } [15]=> array(4) { [0]=> int(15) [1]=> int(16) [2]=> string(4) "attr" [3]=> string(3) "end" } [16]=> array(4) { [0]=> int(16) [1]=> int(17) [2]=> string(4) "call" [3]=> array(0) { } } [17]=> array(4) { [0]=> int(1) [1]=> int(18) [2]=> string(4) "attr" [3]=> string(4) "find" } [18]=> array(4) { [0]=> int(18) [1]=> int(19) [2]=> string(4) "call" [3]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(12) "*[name=text]" } } [19]=> array(4) { [0]=> int(19) [1]=> int(20) [2]=> string(4) "attr" [3]=> string(3) "val" } [20]=> array(4) { [0]=> int(20) [1]=> int(21) [2]=> string(4) "call" [3]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(0) "" } } [21]=> array(4) { [0]=> int(21) [1]=> int(22) [2]=> string(4) "attr" [3]=> string(3) "end" } [22]=> array(4) { [0]=> int(22) [1]=> int(23) [2]=> string(4) "call" [3]=> array(0) { } } [23]=> array(4) { [0]=> int(1) [1]=> int(24) [2]=> string(4) "attr" [3]=> string(4) "find" } [24]=> array(4) { [0]=> int(24) [1]=> int(25) [2]=> string(4) "call" [3]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(13) "*[name=title]" } } [25]=> array(4) { [0]=> int(25) [1]=> int(26) [2]=> string(4) "attr" [3]=> string(3) "val" } [26]=> array(4) { [0]=> int(26) [1]=> int(27) [2]=> string(4) "call" [3]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(1) " " } } [27]=> array(4) { [0]=> int(27) [1]=> int(28) [2]=> string(4) "attr" [3]=> string(3) "end" } [28]=> array(4) { [0]=> int(28) [1]=> int(29) [2]=> string(4) "call" [3]=> array(0) { } } } ["success"]=> bool(true) }
```

Answer (score 1):

The code you gave mean you were calling `json_decode($response)`. This return an object.

It should be:

```
$resArray = json_decode($response, true)
```

Which return an associated array.

Then to use:

```
if (isset($resArray['success'])) {
    //your logic here
}
```

Comment: It doesn't _need_ to be decoded to an array. You can get the same data from it if it's an object - it's just a matter of what you prefer working with.

Comment: Agreed. But above is safe code along. Your code would need to check by `property_exist($res, 'success')`

Comment: That's a good point. I think I'll edit my answer to address that.

Comment: Perfect. Both way are ok now and totally depend on how the style of developer.

Answer (score 1):

Your object has two properties: `jquery` and `success`.

All you need to get the success property is this:

```
$success = $your_object->success;
```

As long as the returned object has a `success` property, that's all you should need to do, regardless of how many other properties it has, or the size of any of its other properties.

If you aren't sure if the object will have the `success` property, you can use

```
$success = !empty($your_object->success);
```

which will evaluate to true if the property exists and is true, and false otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to just throw it into
[json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)

If it complains about the format you can do some direct string manipulation beforehand and then you'll be able to reference it directly as an associative array.

Use var_dump to get familiar with the structure after you get a successful parse.